# Language detection in an e-mail

Tags: php, html, wordpress, email, translation

I am working on a Wordpress website with a plug-in (WP-Rentals) sending various e-mails to clients. This website is multilingual (using Weglot) but I am stuck on finding a solution to have e-mails being sent (or at least received) in the user's language.

The only way I see how to do it would involve a fair bit of modification of the plug-in.

Is it possible to use browser language detection in an e-mail to display the text in the viewer's language ? I am open to any smart and fast solutions !

Comment: email client != browser

Comment: No. There are no ways to code an email to detect the recipient's language. You need to store preferred language in your customer database and deliver different emails dependent on that. That includes the lang attribute

Comment: `Is it possible to use browser language detection in an e-mail`...not if the email isn't opened in a browser...

Comment: How did you get your client email ? Start from there.